# HL7 Conformance Profile Options

Tags: validation, hl7, hl7-v2

Are there any tools out there available that can be used to create conformance Profile other than Messaging Workbench (MWB). So far this is the only tool that I have found

I am having a difficult time creating a conformance profile on for a particular messaging specification in MWB due to the complexity and lack of documentation of the MWB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you’d like to create conformance profiles by scratch, or by generating rules from existing messages then I recommend you use the HL7 Soup tool.

They have a video on the subject here that will cover how to create the rules, and get you started.

http://www.hl7soup.com/ValidateHighlightAndCompare.html

Once you’ve created the profile it can be exported to others.

Comment: Please elaborate on the functionality of this application in regard to conformance profiles. Is this application able to read a current conformance profile in XML? Is this application able to generate a non-proprietary profile in XML correct conformance profile format?

Answer (score 0):

To build conformance profiles from scratch or from existing messages, you may take a look at Caristix Conformance (http://caristix.com/hl7-tools/conformance/scope-hl7-interfaces/). Once you have the conformance profile set, you can compare it with another profile (or set of messages) an get a gap analysis report.

This tool is much easier to use than Messaging Workbench.

Disclaimer: I'm part of the team developing this tool.

Comment: Please elaborate on the functionality of this application in regard to conformance profiles. Is this application able to read a current conformance profile in XML? Is this application able to generate a non-proprietary profile in XML correct conformance profile format?

Comment: If you are referring to the Messaging Workbench format, it can import from or export to this format using an add-on (http://caristix.com/hl7-tools/hl7-connectors/messaging-workbench/). It can also export/import from/to several integration engine proprietary format. On top of that, it can help you manage profile versioning, documentation generation and several other productivity features.